# Django test command fail after changing models.py to a directory structure

Tags: python, django

This is in Django 2.0 , python 3.6.5

I have an app called posts, and I changed models.py to a folder structure, i.e., create a directory models and move the file models.py insid. Also config __ init__.py file, as explained next.
The project runs ok, but my test suite fails.

In my settings, installed apps i have the app as:

```
'myproject.apps.posts.apps.PostsConfig'
```

My app config (posts/apps.py)

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class PostsConfig(AppConfig):    
    name = 'posts'               
    verbose_name = 'posts'
```

I have move posts/models.py to a directory structure. So I have

```
posts/models/models.py
posts/models/proxymodels.py
posts/models/__init__.py
```

inside models/__ init__.py I do import my models as explained in doc

```
from .models import Job
from .proxys import ActiveJob
```

The project works well, but when trying to run tests:

```
python manage.py test
```

I have this error:

```
RuntimeError: Model class tektank.apps.posts.models.models.Job doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

The model is a normal one, with fields, nothing extrange. The thing is that if I declare in the meta

```
class Meta:
    app_label = 'posts'
```

I got the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Conflicting 'job' models in application 'posts': <class 'posts.models.models.Job'> and <class 'tektank.apps.posts.models.models.Job'>.
```

Note: If I use pytest, I run the command:

```
pytest
```

It runs OK

**UPDATE**

Same error if I execute:

```
./manage.py test myproject/apps/posts
```

If I execute only with app name, no tests are detected

```
./manage.py test posts
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
OK
```

If I put the path of the tests folder, **it works ok**.

```
./manage.py test myproject/apps/posts/tests
Ran 2 tests in 0.074s
OK
./manage.py test posts.tests
Ran 2 tests in 0.103s
OK
```

But **I am not satisfied with this**, if I want to run all tests, it will still fail.

Comment: try `./manage.py test Job` for Job aplication test

Comment: @NVS, updated with more test cases.